# Libreoffice special character appears as question marks

Tags: csv, libreoffice, character-encoding

I'm trying to use a .csv sent to me by another individual. When I look inside at the data, special characters such as quotation marks, hyphens and apostrophes appear as question marks or special characters.

When opening the .csv, I select UTF-8 and use the correct delimiters - suggested to me by other answers I looked at before posting here.

What is the issue? The encoding is correct, when I open the file using Notepad++ the encoding is set correctly.

Thanks for your time

Comment: What encoding is Notepad++ is using?  Check [Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090845/change-the-default-encoding-for-notepad).  Also be sure to try UTF-16 in LibreOffice, since that is common among Windows users especially.

Comment: @JimK thanks for the reply! Notepad++ is using UTF-8, UTF-16 causes the text to look chinese. When opening the document in LibreOffice, I've tried every single character set, but the text still doesn't look correct. The .csv is to be used with Magento import, but the special character issues causes errors on import.